# Is the spoiler code non-functional in Internet Explorer?

Tags: bug, status-completed, spoilers

Considering that IE and Windows XP own significant (if not still majority) shares in their respective markets, I find it hard to believe that a feature would be implemented here which does not work in those environments.  However, I've tested this in one machine with IE 7 and another with IE 8, both running Windows XP SP3, and the code does not work for me.

Is it just me, or is this a known issue?

Comment: I don't know if it's "known," but I can confirm it doesn't work in IE8.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A fix for this will go out in the next build.

The CSS for sketchy(meta) sites has a bit of hack for blockquote's, and I missed that hack when adapting them for the new spoiler syntax.

Comment: Again, this issue is not isolated to meta sites.  The issue is seen on the parent site as well.  Why do we keep getting told this?

Comment: @Iszi - the same fix is being applied to parent sites.  "sketchy(meta)" is generally read as "sketchy and sketchymeta" just like S(OFU) is read as "SO and SF and SU".