# Should the spoiler code work in IE Tab Plus?

Tags: bug, status-declined, spoilers

I'm sure this will probably end up a "no", but I thought I would throw it in to make sure the devs are aware.

I normally use [IE Tab Plus (FKA: Coral IE Tab)](http://coralietab.mozdev.org/) for any browsing that *absolutely* requires a site to be rendered in IE.  As such, it was my first choice to verify that the new spoiler code update indeed did [work in Internet Explorer](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/767/is-the-spoiler-code-non-functional-in-internet-explorer).

However, for me, the spoiler code is still broken in IE Tab Plus.  To be sure, I went and loaded the real Internet Explorer.  Sure enough, the code works there.  I'm not sure what the difference is (I thought IE Tab Plus just used the resident copy of IE on the system) but it seems the spoiler code is still broken for IE Tab Plus users.

I really don't know who would even want to load RPG.se in IE Tab Plus, since it works perfectly fine in Firefox, but again just wanted to make sure the devs are aware of this issue so that they can decide how (or if) to address it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like IE Tab has problems with this kind of color fallback for non-RGBA-aware browsers:

```
.spoiler, .spoiler a
{
    color: #fffdf4;
    color: rgba(255,253,244, 0.8);
}
```

It happens in several places; it's just particularly visible for the spoilers. For example, you may notice that the light blue background for the question asker's signature is missing as well.

And you're right, this is a little too obscure a "browser" for us to worry about working around its bugs – sorry :)

You might want to [report this to the IE Tab team](https://www.mozdev.org/), though.